# MySQL / PHP: Returning the row values that contain the MAX value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a quiz results table.  Users can take it over and over again for each category - I need their highest score for each category and the corresponding timestamp.

So I'm really close but the timestamp field is killing me.

Here's one users data: ("score" is varchar with %s - that's what I was handed.  Also sorted by category, then highest score, then timestamp.  If I could just take the first row for each category I'm done.)

```
catid  score   timestamp
5   100%    2012-03-22 19:26:41
6   88.89%  2012-06-12 15:20:41
6   77.78%  2012-06-12 15:17:58
7   100%    2012-06-12 16:08:35
7   100%    2012-06-12 16:03:35
7   53.33%  2012-06-12 15:59:44
8   88.89%  2012-06-12 16:13:00
9   83.33%  2012-06-12 16:22:19
10  100%    2012-06-12 17:55:50
10  76.47%  2012-06-12 17:51:54
11  100%    2012-06-12 18:07:12
11  66.67%  2012-06-12 18:05:35
```

Here's what I need:

```
catid  score          timestamp
5   100%    2012-03-22 19:26:41
6   88.89%  2012-06-12 15:20:41
7   100%    2012-06-12 16:08:35
8   88.89%  2012-06-12 16:13:00
9   83.33%  2012-06-12 16:22:19
10  100%    2012-06-12 17:55:50
11  100%    2012-06-12 18:07:12
```

Here's the MySQL I'm using:

```
SELECT catid
 , MAX(0 + score)
 , `timestamp`

FROM `results` 
WHERE userid = 100
GROUP BY catid
ORDER BY catid ASC
 , (0 + score) DESC
 , timestamp DESC
;
```

And the table it's producing:

```
5   100 2012-03-22 19:26:41
6   88.89   2012-06-12 15:17:58
7   100 2012-06-12 15:59:44
8   88.89   2012-06-12 16:13:00
9   83.33   2012-06-12 16:22:19
10  100 2012-06-12 17:51:54
11  100 2012-06-12 18:05:35
```

So close - but the timestamp isn't the one associated with the highest value.  What's going on and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the link - I actually read about 30-40 threads for the last few hours before posting.  See if I can dig into that link more the thread linked within there is a little more useful though as the comments point out not ideal.

Comment: They can't unless the system crapped completely out.  I'd just want one value.  Ideally give me the max(0+score) and then the most recent timestamp for that.  [yes, most recent]

Comment: You haven't specified what should happen if a user has two scores that are the same (and maximum) but with the different timestamps. Do you want the most recent in this case? (Sorry my previous comment was wrong - I deleted it. This comment is what I meant to ask.)

Comment: Also, are there other columns in this table that you also need, or are those the only columns?

Comment: Yes - exactly, the most recent! :) Those are the only columns I need.

Answer (score 2):

Your table would be 328 times more awesome if you used a numeric type to store the percentages instead of a string. However, for this answer I'll ignore this issue, though you really should fix it as soon as possible.

You can solve your problem as follows:

```
SELECT catid, score, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM results
WHERE userid = 100
AND (catid, CAST(score AS DECIMAL(5,2))) IN
(
    SELECT catid, MAX(CAST(score AS DECIMAL(5,2))) AS score
    FROM results
    WHERE userid = 100
    GROUP BY catid   
)
GROUP BY catid
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52b82/10)

Or with the datetimes formatted as strings: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52b82/11)

**Results**

```
CATID   SCORE   TIMESTAMP
5       100%    2012-03-22 19:26:41
6       88.89%  2012-06-12 15:20:41
7       100%    2012-06-12 16:08:35
8       88.89%  2012-06-12 16:13:00
9       83.33%  2012-06-12 16:22:19
10      100%    2012-06-12 17:55:50
11      100%    2012-06-12 18:07:12
```

Comment: Awesome!  @numeric type: Yeah, I didn't make the original system with the data, that was the first thing I had to adjust.  One thing though - since there are a lot of users I need to call a specific userid (above see my WHERE statement).  I tried putting that in but it's not giving me the right values - how would I do that?  Thank you!

Comment: @Gisto: Did you put it in both selects?

Comment: Yes, though when I put it in the first select (or more specifically `WHERE (catid, userid=100, CAST(score AS DECIMAL(5,2))) IN` )it said "Operand should contain 3 columns", if it's just in the second then it's pulling other user timestamps in.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(score), catid, timestamp FROM db.table GROUP BY catid ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Comment: You would also need to add the timestamp to the group by

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately that gave me the same incorrect table as above (where the timestamp is not associated with the actual MAX value).  When I added the timestamp to the group by then it returned multiple values for each catid (similar to the first table I posted above).

Comment: Unfortunately same mismatch as above :/